# Access to all site collections

Tags: 2010, 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, administration

I need to give users access to manage all site collections. Where is the best place to specify this? I would like one place to give users access to all site collections.

Comment: site collection in same web application or different?

Answer (score 1):

You can manage permissions at web application level.

```
On the SharePoint Central Administration website, in the Application Management section, click Manage web applications.
On the WEB APPLICATIONS tab of the ribbon, click the web application for which you want to manage permissions.
In the Security group of the ribbon, click User Permissions.
In the User Permissions for Web Application dialog box, select the check boxes next to the permissions that you want to enable, and clear the check boxes next to those permissions that you want to disable.
You can select all permissions by selecting the Select All check box. You can clear all permissions by clearing the Select All check box.
Click Save.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via Web Application user policy from Central Admin.
But their is an issue with this approach, when you add user into the policy of web app then he will access all site collections in that web App and you cannot restrict him.
Adding too much user in this group high risk for security.

I would prefer site collection primary & secondary site collection admin approach.

You can assign Primary & secondry site collection admin from central admin.

- Central admin > Application management > change site collection
  Administrators.
- select the site collection from top right.
- Now you can change it here.
- repeat this for each site collection.

Now let the site collection admin to handle security for each site collection.

Another way is use the 3rd party tools.